# how to use a function to fill an object?

Tags: typescript

I try to write function that check string. If string has repeating symbols then that function return false. If string has not repeating symbols then one return true. This is my  attempt:

```
function isIsogram(str: string): boolean {
  const lower = str.toLocaleLowerCase();
  let db: Record<string, number> = {};

  db = lower.split('').reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (item in acc) {
      acc[item]++; // error: Element implicitly has an 'any'
    } else {
      acc[item] = 1; // error: Element implicitly has an 'any'
    }

    return acc;
  }, {});

  return Object.values(db).every((i) => i === 1);
}

console.log(isIsogram('')); // true
console.log(isIsogram('Dermatoglyphics')); // true
console.log(isIsogram('isogram')); // true
console.log(isIsogram('aba')); // false
console.log(isIsogram('moOse')); // false
console.log(isIsogram('isIsogram')); // false
```

[live demo is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-7vr68w?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

This is right working code, however i get the following error message from typescript parser:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.   No index signature with a
> parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.(7053)

Please help me to fix my code. I need to get rid of that error message. But i need use namely reduce() function.

Comment: TS doesn't know that the initial object `{}` is going to be used as a number dictionary. You can manually specify that when calling `reduce()` as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wedLKW).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial value of the reduce function is untyped, so `acc` is also untyped. The template argument of reduce solves the issue.

```js
interface AssociativeNumberArray {
  [key: string]: number
}

[...]

  db = lower.split('').reduce<AssociativeNumberArray>((acc, item) => {
```